# pyQT The event loop is already running

Tags: python, pyqt

iam just a student and iam building a project in Python using PyQt the problem is the follwing :

I have to files , main.py and admin.py.

i want to call the admin.py class in main.py to show the page so i did this

```
`def show_admin():
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(None, "success", "logged in as admin")
    from admin import main
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but i get this error :
`QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running`

inside the admin.py i only have the class main

can someone help me to fix this issue

we  did try to get a reference to the current application using the QApplication.instance() method and call its quit method to close the current window , we create an instance of the main class from the admin.py file and call its show method to open the main window.

```
def show_admin():
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(None, "success", "logged in as admin")
    from admin import main
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why are you trying to run the event loop again?

Comment: Hey , iam not trying to run the event loop , i get this error and i want to fix the event loop

Comment: Yes, you are, that's what `app.exec()` does. Besides, only *one* QApplication instance should ever exist, so creating a new one is also wrong. In any case, it's unclear what calls those functions, so please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create multiple `QApplicaion` instances. Assuming your `admin.main()` returns a `QWindow`, do like this.

```
def show_admin():
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(None, "success", "logged in as admin")
    from admin import main
    window = main()
    window.show()
```

But I suggest using the `QDialog` instead of the `QWindow`, if you already created a main window.